# Assitance with C++ using pseudocode code (overflow/underflow)

Tags: c++, overflow, underflow

I'm barely into my 4th week of C++ in school and was looking to be guided in the right direction.

```
 #include "std_lib_facilities_3.h"

class BadArea{};

int area(int length, int width){
    if(length <= 0 || width <=0) throw BadArea();
    return length * width;
}

double mysqrt(double x){
    if(x < 0.0) error("mysqrt");
    return 1.0; //dummy value for now, need to write code later
}

int main(){
    try{
        char length = 0;
        char width = 0;
        cout << "Enter length and width seperated by a space\n";
        cin >> length;
        cin >> width;
        vector<double> v(10);
        v[9] = 7.5;
        cout << area(7, -10) << '\n';
        cout << mysqrt(-2.0) << '\n';
        return 0;
    }
    catch(BadArea){
        cerr << "Exception: Bad area\n";
    }
    catch(exception& e){
        cerr << "ExceptionZ: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    catch(...){
        cerr << "Exception occurred\n";
    }
}
```

And this is what the assignment is asking us;

```
   //Check for overflow in the area function
      result = length * width
      if result is negative or result/length <> width, throw an exception
  //Use 3 iterations of the Newton-Raphson method for mysqrt
      if x is 0, result is 0 so return it
      if x is 1, result is 1 so return it
      otherwise,
         result = (x^4 + 28x^3 + 70x^2 + 28x + 1)/(8*(1 + x)*(1 + 6x + x^2))
```

> Change the main to have an infinite loop around the try/catch part; in the try
>   block ask for length and width; if cin fails then return, otherwise print 
>   the area, and print mysqrt of the area.  Name your program hw3pr2.cpp.  (Recall 
>   that cin will fail if you type something that is not a properly-formatted int,
>   e.g., the word "end".)

I understand how to read the code, but I'm having a hard time starting it, and sort of get confused with "scope" so far it compiles correctly but keeps on giving me Range Error: 10. does that mean I'm using the class area wrong?

could someone please point me in the right direction? 
Thank you!

Comment: Please don't use the homework tag. It's deprecated.

Comment: What purpose does the vector serve?  It isn't being used, and doesn't seem to relate at all to the rest of your data.  Also, what part of the problem are you having trouble with?  The infinite loop?  I assume the "range error" was taken care of when you changed the 10 to a 9...

Comment: @Ross, I'm not really sure. that was the code that the professor provided for us.

Comment: please edit your post to show the current error you're getting after you fixed the range error problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a vector of 10 elements and trying to access the 11th item with `v[10]`.

[EDIT] As others have pointed out, std::vector doesn't do bounds checking by default, but if "std_lib_facilities_3.h" is similar to [this](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h), then it defines its own range-checked vector class.

[EDIT2] So you've updated your code so that length and width must be both greater than 0 or an BadArea exception will be thrown, but you're always calling `area(7, -10)`, so you'll always get the exception.  I think you want to pass the length and width to the area function: `cout << area(length, width) << '\n';`

Comment: yeah I saw that, since this is code provided by the professor, I have to correct it as well. I forgot to add the correction.

Comment: Could be it...although last i heard, `std::vector::operator[]` didn't do bounds checks.

Comment: after the fix, I still Exception: mysqrt -------- also, the original code had if(length <= 0 || width <=0) so if fixed the width as well.

Comment: @enigmuz, That should be right. If the length is less than 0, or the width is less than 0, the area isn't going to be right and makes no sense to calculate. Your version will fail if both are positive like they should be.

Comment: @cHao : Most standard library implementations optionally do bounds checks in debug mode (usually in the form of an `assert`).

Comment: why exactly is checking both to be positive incorrect ? the code in the question above has width >=0, which is correct? and whichever it is, kindly update the code above please.

Comment: @cHao: I wasn't able to reproduce his error on my machine, but that was the only thing that seemed strange about the op's code.

Comment: @ildjarn: that explains it then, seeing that the RangeError went away after the change. Good to know.

Comment: Or not. Apparently Stroustrup's beginner C++ books make use of a similar header (which the op's included header is likely based on) that provides a simple range-checked wrapper around std::vector.

Comment: @chris, ohh gotcha, I'll make sure to edit it back then. you're right.


This is my output when I run it with the given code above. ------ :: a.out
Enter length and width seperated by a space
4 5
Exception: Bad area ----- I'm using g++ on putty.

Comment: does that mean I have to fix the badarea class? or the if statement on badarea class is incorrect? Sorry I'm just lost.

Comment: the bad area exception is the expected result with the code you posted. You're always passing area a width of -10. See my edit.